# Should I use CursorLoader with RecyclerView?

Tags: android, loader

`RecyclerView` by itself has set of `notifyItem*()` methods which refreshes the `RecyclerView` when it's needed. The question is should I use `CursorLoader` with `RecyclerView` when I load the data from SQLite DB

Comment: CursorLoader extends AsyncTask so when you query using cursorloader it will be on worker thread and after results is fetched it can be set and notified to recyclerview.

Comment: @SagarPujari The question is does the notifyItem*() methods works asynchronously?

Comment: onLoadFinished wiil be called in the main thread where you will get cursor with data fetched in it and notify item will be done in main thread only.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `RecyclerView`, you should use the `CursorLoader` to receive the actual data for your list, but unlike the ListView, the RecyclerView does not give you the instant method for swapping data from SQLite database or from some content provider. You should do it by yourself.

Comment: Do it by yourself? Copy an existing implementation... https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b

Comment: @cricket_007 Simply I did not give the link, because it can be easily found in the web.